# Scanf in C # windows form?

Tags: c#, scanf, visual-studio-2019

my question is why I can't 
recognize keyboard input in windows form?
Can someone put me a sample code?

I want to be able to read keyboard input from a textbox in windows form and display with a button it in a messagebox for testing, but that doesn't read anything.

```
public button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string s = Console.Readline();

    Convert.ToInt32(s);
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: either use Text property or subscribe for keys events

Comment: This doesn't work because you are mixing Windows Form UI and console functions.

Comment: Put some `TextBox` (say, `myTextBox`) on the form, then you can read `Text` value from it: `string s = myTextBox.Text;`

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no Console in Windows forms you can not read from it. On Textbox you can subscribe to events and do what you want.
[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)